# Can't start oracle after recovery

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to import the database to another instance. So I imported the database with `restore controlfile`, `restore database` and `recover database` command.

When I try to start the database, it complains:

```
ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced
ORA-00704: bootstrap process failure
ORA-39700: database must be opened with UPGRADE option
Process ID: 14134
Session ID: 969 Serial number: 5700
```

How can I finish the recover process? I can do `startup upgrade`, but what next? I'm not running a upgrade job, just migrating the database to a new server.

Comment: First off, this is not "importing" a database.  Importing is done with one of the two import utilities, either 'impdp' or the older 'imp'.  What you are doing is restoring from a backup, and it appears that the new location is using a newer ORACLE_HOME than the one from which the rman backup was made.  Please confirm.

Comment: @EdStevens I just realized that .. I was restoring a 18c backup to a 19c server, I'll install another 18c server and test again.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you restore the backup with a different version of Oracle software.

Use the same version of Oracle software.

Or you can upgrade the database before opening it normally. For that, use `alter database open resetlogs upgrade;`, and continue with upgrading the database.